# Is there any way to get private field names from a java class in a Declared order

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I am trying to get the names of all private fields in the declared order:

```
for ( PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors( Some.class ) )
    {
        System.out.println(propertyDescriptor.getName());
    }
```

When I try to get them they are given in ascending order by field names.

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. Why is order needed here?

Comment: Same names will be displayed as header string, which should be in order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Class.getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) returns the fields in the order of declaration. To get only the private ones:

```
for (Field field : YourClass.cass.getDeclaredFields())
    if (Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers()))
        System.out.println(field.getName());
```

Note that inherited fields are not included, quoting from the javadoc:

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but **excludes inherited fields**.

For that, you have to do the same for the super class and implemented interfaces (recursively).

**Warning:**

Quoting from the javadoc:

> The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.

The API does not require the returned `Field` array to be sorted in any way, but in practice (Oracle implementation), they are in the same order as you declared them.

Comment: But from the docs we have - *The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.*

Comment: @TheLostMind Well, yes, that's true, the API does not require them to be sorted in any way, but in practice, they are in the same order as you declared them.

Comment: Now that you have added that warning, its fine. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to be sure `Class.getDeclaredFields()` stays the way it behaves today. Oracle can change this at any time in any upcomming JDK!

If order is important to you I sugest to implement a field anotation which allows you to number the fields.

If you want to relay on the order in the code and don't want to relay on the current implementation of `Class.getDeclaredFields()` you have to parse the java source files yourself. [Javaparser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) might save you a lot of time here.